# How to configure modelmapper to skip nested properties in destination

Tags: java, modelmapper

```
Source{
String one;
String two;
}

Destination{
String one;
Child child;
}

Child{
String two;
}

main() {
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
// what configurations to set here?
Source source = new Source("one=1", "two=2");
Destination desiredResult = new Destination();
desiredResult.setOne("one=1");
Destination mappedResult = modelmapper.map(source, Destination.class )
assertEquals(mappedResult,  desiredResult );
}
```

The problem is that modelmapper will map `source.two => destination.child.two`, which I do not want. I have tried methods like

```
1. modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPreferNestedProperties(false);
2. modelMapper.getConfiguration().setAmbiguityIgnored(true);
3. modelMapper.getConfiguration().setImplicitMappingEnabled(false);
4. modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Source, Destination>() {
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
        skip(destination.getChild());
        skip(destination.getChild().getTwo());
      }
    });
```

None worked.

I hope to have a general solution that can stop model mapper to map any nested object's properties in destination object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you perhaps be missing some preexisting configuration? Your example works just fine for me.

Anyway, such things happen mostly when you are using `LOOSE` matching strategy.

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
```

You can fix it by explicitly setting matching strategy to `STANDARD` or `STRICT`.

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STANDARD);
```

Or

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
```

Check the [docs](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/#:%7E:text=Default%20configuration%20uses%20the%20Standard,according%20to%20the%20JavaBeans%20convention.) for additional info on matching strategies, naming conventions, default configurations, etc.